# Stop emacs from wrapping 80 column lines in an 80 column terminal?

Tags: emacs, terminal, line, word-wrap

In an 80 column wide terminal emacs wraps 80 column lines, putting a backslash in the 80th column.  Is there a way to tell emacs to use all 80 columns of my terminal and not wrap lines until they reach 81 characters?

Comment: Well, I've achieved part of what I want, using truncate-lines, disabling auto-hscroll-mode, and longlines-mode together.  With this setup, 80-column lines aren't wrapped, and 81-column lines are soft-word-wrapped.  The only problem is that 80 column lines don't show the last character; they show '$' instead, while 81+ character lines don't show any wrapping indicator.  I'd prefer the opposite.

Comment: No. I use Sublime Text now.

Comment: Can I run that in a terminal over SSH?

Comment: Good options for remoting Sublime Text are X forwarding or SSHFS. Personally I find SSHFS to work surprisingly well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, this is not about logical line
wrapping (how lines are segmented in your file), but about visual wrapping
(how lines are displayed with respect to window width).

- If you just want the display to *visually* wrap more than zero characters before
  window boundary, and thus **avoid the backslash** everywhere, however long your logical lines really are, you can use [longlines-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Longlines.html)
  :

  > Unlike Visual Line mode, Long Lines mode breaks long lines at the fill column (see Fill Commands), rather than the right window edge. To enable Long Lines mode, type M-x longlines-mode. If the text is full of long lines, this also immediately “wraps” them all.

  Then, it's only a matter of setting the fill-column appropriately, using
  either global settings (`.emacs`, though you probably want to use a
  specific mode-hook for that particular case), local settings (file
  variable, dir-locals) or <kbd>C-u</kbd> 79 <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd>
  <kbd>f</kbd> to set variable `fill-column` to 79. This way, lines 79
  characters or higher will wrap, but before touching the right edge of the
  80-char window (and thus never leaving an ugly backslash character). Your
  file will be untouched.
- If you simply want no visual wrapping to occur on 80-character lines, and thus do not want the 80th logical character visually displayed below the first, there are two
  possible answers:

  - either you work in an environment where you don't necessarily wrap
    *logically* at or before 80 characters, and you want to see the end of
    those 81+ lines somewhere in your screen (i.e. you do want visual wrap, but at a number of chars above the window width), then *I don't know how to do
    it*.
  - or you want to stop your lines at 80 chars logically (e.g. you
    have auto-fill on and fill-column at 80), and if you do happen to have
    lines 81 characters or more, you don't care about seeing their ending.
    In that case, activate [truncate-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TruncateLines) (`toggle-truncate-lines`).
- If the issue is about the last character of your window, and what you really want is **the 80th logical character of your line to be displayed on the 80th visual character of your window**, though, I'm afraid I don't know how. Either you are truncating lines (as above), and the last character of your window will be a $, or you let [emacs do its thing](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Continuation-Lines.html), and the last character will be a backslash.

Note when testing that auto-fill's wrapping (but also longlines-mode's, since it is its visual equivalent) will occur only at word boundaries.

Comment: Have you tried it? In longlines-mode with fill-column 81 in an 80 column terminal, 80 and 81 column lines still wrap with a backslash. 82-character lines are soft-word-wrapped.  I don't care what happens to 81 character or longer lines; I just want 80 character lines to not wrap.

Comment: Yes, I want the 80th character to be displayed in the 80th column of my terminal.  I'll settle for the combination of truncate-mode, longlines-mode and disabling horizontal scrolling. With this setup 80 character lines aren't wrapped, and 81 character lines are visually word wrapped.  I do get $ in the 80th column instead of the actual character and I don't see any way to disable that, but I'll take it over the unnecessary wrapping that is the default.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to set the wrapping to happen at 81, instead of 80.

```
M-x set-fill-column RET 81
```

Another option, maybe the best choice, is to define the variable overflow-newline-into-fringe as t. Try this once, manually:

```
M-x set-variable RET overflow-newline-into-fringe RET t
```

Either of these could be set by default. You can do that through `M-x customize` or by editing your .emacs file. Post again if you need help.

BTW, do you use emacs in a graphical or terminal environment? In a graphical environment, I often just make the window larger if I have long lines. Or I may turn on line truncation with a horizontal scrollbar.

---

### added later

With the added information that you are running emacs in terminal mode, as you discovered, none of those options work. I tried an example running emacs in putty, where I can change the size of the window and emacs picks it right up. So, I could size to 81 columns and my 80-column lines remain intact without continuation. I am not sure which TERM value you have assigned with tmux, but you could consider creating a custom terminal type (termcap or terminfo) which supports 81 columns. I only took a brief glance at tmux but I noticed that you can resize panes within a terminal.

Now, out of curiosity, what is the primary motivator for you using tmux? I would think that the resume capability would be valuable. I would find however, that the other features are not that useful because in an X-Window environment it is cheap & easy to open more terminals or if I am using putty, I can create more of those. As far as using emacs, whether I am running under X-Window or MS-Windows, I just create as many frames as I would like and can work quite easily with that. So, is there something else that makes you interested in using tmux?

Comment: set-fill-column doesn't have the effect I want. It controls the behavior of M-q, not the visual wrapping behavior of the window. overflow-newline-into-fringe sounds like what I want but it doesn't appear to have any effect when running in a terminal, which is how I run emacs (to take advantage of tmux).

Comment: I use tmux so I can connect via ssh to the same set of terminals I have open on my local display (including emacs), and also so emacs isn't killed when my remote connection dies.  I can definitely resize all my terminals to 81 characters wide but it's rather annoying as the default is always 80, so I have to remember to change it on every machine I use, and that unused column just wastes space.  First world problems, I know.

Comment: Setting the value of `overflow-newline-into-fringe` to `t` (actually, it's set to that by default) doesn't have the advertised effect when using Emacs in a separate GUI window, either: switching its values between `nil` and `t`  has no effect, and the line wraps visually the moment the visual line is filled. (I'm using Emacs v24.2 on Xubuntu.) (In GUI mode, the cursor is supposed to be displayed in the "fringe", which is also used for line continuation symbols, and for marking a nonexistent line if `indicate-empty-lines` has been set to `t`.)

Answer (score 1):

Six years after the previous answers and the workaround I still use is to use 81 character-wide windows.

Unfortunately 80-wide windows that wrap 'correctly' are not possible because of evil fringe characters.  Emacs requires the last (fringe) character to have exclusive use of the final column.  The argument for this is an optional fringe character is ambiguous.  I dream of the day someone will submit a patch to make the fringe character optional, and perhaps solving the ambiguity with a background color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is prossible in general, because emacs needs at least one character to indicate that the line continues in the next line (wraps), although I'm not sure, because emacs has so many options... You could maybe instead select "Word Wrap (Visual Line Mode)" in the "Options" menu (or keyboard):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> visual-line-mode<kbd>RET</kbd>

This makes the flow more natural, without showing (at least in text modes) the indication of wrapping.

Comment: Visual line mode doesn't help, no matter what fill-column is set to; 80 character lines still wrap.